GeoNode upload dataset failed
I installed latest version of GeoNode (should be version 4.3.1) using docker, on Ubuntu 22.04, inside LXC container, following the instruction here: https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/install/advanced/core/index.html#docker
.env file created using this command:
python3 create-envfile.py --env_type test --hostname mydummydomain.com

Inside LXC host, I create nginx reverse proxy like this:
server {                                                                                      
    listen 80;                                                                                
    server_name mydummydomain.com;                                                               
                                                                                              
    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS                                                     
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                                                     
}                                                                                             
                                                                                              
server {                                                                                      
    listen 443 ssl;                                                                           
    server_name mydummydomain.com;                                                               
                                                                                              
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydummydomain.com.crt;                                        
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydummydomain.com.key;                                    
                                                                                              
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;                                                            
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;                                                             
                                                                                              
    location / {                                                                              
        proxy_pass http://10.11.12.13/;  # my LXC container IP address                          
        proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                          
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                              
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                          
                                                                                      
        # Timeout settings                                                                    
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;                                                          
        proxy_send_timeout 3600s;                                                             
        proxy_read_timeout 3600s;                                                             
        proxy_buffering off;                                                                  
    }                                                                                         
                                                                                              
}                                                                                             

When I try to upload data (zipped shapefile, actually) on mydummydomain.com, I got ERROR 500 and result like this:
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
    ],
    "code": "method_not_allowed"
}

when accessing this URL:
https://mydummydomain.com/proxy/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmydummydomain.com%2Fapi%2Fv2%2Fuploads%2Fupload

What have I done wrong?
